# C++ unable to use peek() function in stack

Tags: c++, stack, peek

I am trying to use the `peek` function in Visual Studio 2010 with these libraries:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
```

However, I cannot use the `peek` function in the stack:

```
void dfs(){
    stack<Node> s;
    s.push(nodeArr[root]);
    nodeArr[root].setVisited();
    nodeArr[root].print();
    while(!s.empty()){
        //peek yok?!
        Node n=s.peek();        
        if(!n.below->isVisited()){
            n.below->setVisited();
            n.below->print();
            s.push(*n.below);
        }
        else{
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Error 1 error C2039: 'peek' : is not a member of 'std::stack<_Ty>'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `stack` reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `peek` function in `std::stack`.

Are you looking for `top()`?

```
void dfs(){
    stack<Node> s;
    s.push(nodeArr[root]);
    nodeArr[root].setVisited();
    nodeArr[root].print();
    while(!s.empty()){
        //peek yok?!
        Node n=s.top();   // <-- top here
        if(!n.below->isVisited()){
            n.below->setVisited();
            n.below->print();
            s.push(*n.below);
        }
        else{
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all so much. in msdn, when i saw reference to peek, i guess i am in the true way. but you are right, i was wrong. thank you again for replies.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want to use

```
s.top();
```

instead of peak.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `peek` function in std::stack. For a reference, please see [stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/)

It looks as if you are using the functionality as `top` would be. For a reference on top, take a look at [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/top/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has `stack`, but you actually wanted to use `Stack`.  They are two different things.

Comment: Here's the doc on the Stack you wanted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w32446f.aspx#Y0